# Set a list of objects as a request body: Spring WebClient

Tags: spring, mongodb, post, spring-webclient

I'm building Spring/MongoDB RESTful web service and I would like to set a list of objects *(mongoDB models)* as a body of POST request using Spring WebClient:

```
public void postProducts(List<Product> products) {
        return this.webClient.post(
                .uri("/products")
                .body(Mono.just(products), Product.class)
                .retrieve();
}
```

However,

```
.body(Mono.just(products), Products.class)
```

is wrong way of setting a list of objects *(List-Product-)* as a request body.

Would you propose the right way of doing that?
I'd be grateful for your answers:)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public void postProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.webClient.post(
            .uri("/products")
            .body(Mono.just(products), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Product>>() {})
            .retrieve();
}
```